# How to map a key to toggle keymap function?

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to map a function key to turn on a specific keyboard layout, like `set keymap=x`, and toggle it on second keypress as in CTRL+Shift+^.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Does `i_CTRL-^` not work for you to toggle? Or are you looking for something like `:inoremap XXX <C-^>`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks for the reply. The shortcut works, but I am looking to only turn on the keymap when needed, and keep it turned off at other times. That's why I am looking for something like `inoremap <F5> keymap=xxx` etc.